Catch internal revert
Is it possible to catch a revert in like an internal decoding? For example:
function mint(
        bytes memory data_, 
        address owner_
    ) returns(uint) {
...
 (AmountsIn memory amts, address receiver) = abi.decode(data_, (AmountsIn, address));
...
}

If that decode fails, revert with a custom error.
I know about try/catch but that only works in external calls.
